# Is there any way to set the wifi permission programatically for iOS using ionic?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins, wifi

Actually I have created an iOS application using ionic to connect and disconnect from a particular network using wifiWizard2 Cordova Plugin.

But when I am trying to connect,Popup flashes and asks for "WiFi wants to join Wi-Fi Network "xxxx"".WiFi is my application name.
Then there is 2 option cancel | join.
How to remove this popup so that when I click on connect it should directly connect to the particular network I have specified.

Comment: thats a system popup for security/privacy, i dont think you can remove it.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any other way I can connect to the wifi using ionic.